# Can not update Twitter via Fabric because it open MyProject.xcodeproj

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, twitter-fabric

In my project, when I open `MyProject.xcodeproj` I got an issue

> No such module 'SocketIOClientSwift'

And when I open `MyProject.xcworkspace` everything work fine

Then when I try to update the `Twitter` via **Fabric**, **Fabric automatically open** `MyProject.xcodeproj` and it say
[image]

But my `MyProject.xcodeproj` have a problem so it can not build.
How can I update Twitter now? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: are you using pods in your project correct, if yes you need to open `MyProject.xcworkspace` not `MyProject.xcodeproj`

Comment: I think I use it correct because everything work fine if I open `MyProject.xcworkspace`

Comment: if everyting fine close your question its my suggestion, if you have a any other question related to this ask here

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik my question is different. sorry for my bad explains but please consider it again

Comment: no no bro , fabric not open your existing project, if you set up the twitter in your code , you need to manodatry complete the some few steps, thats all, if completed the all things it automaticlly redirect to your app

Comment: you are right, fabric don't open existing project. When I use fabric I quit Xcode, then I update Twitter via Fabric, it auto open `MyProject.xcodeproj` not open `MyProject.xcworkspace`

Comment: ya this is the default setup followed by twitter, so dont worry

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik but then Fabric says I need to build my project (like the image). **But** my project now is `MyProject.xcodeproj`, and it have a error so I can not build for finish update Twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working in `MyProject.xcworkspace` and try to update `Twitter` via `Fabric` it will say

```
Cannot open "MyProject.xcodeproj" because it is already open in another workspace
```

When it happened you **don't need** to quit `Xcode` for open `MyProject.xcodeproj`.
Just simple ignore this alert and build your project. Your Twitter will update